# get a unique integer value given a string

Tags: php

I think it should be easy but I can not do it in any way and I can not find information about it.

I have some PHP strings:

```
$a = "yellow";
$b = "green";
$c = "blue";
$d = "black";
$e = "blue";
```

I need to get unique integer values to use like ID. Something like this:

```
$a = 31;
$b = 52;
$c = 11;
$d = 43;
$e = 11;
```

I try using `ord` but only gets first characther, then in my example with `blue` and `black`doesn't work.

With md5 I get numbers and characters. I need a integer.

```
echo md5("blue"); // this returns 48d6215903dff56238e52e8891380c8f
echo ord("blue"); // this returns 98
echo ord("back"); // this returns 98
```

Comment: Do you mean random unique numbers, or constant over time? By the way, you can just put all these values into an array, and use indexes as your unique values to use as ID.

Comment: share your code..?

Comment: It's not clear to me what result you're hoping to achieve here.  Can't you just assign incrementing values as identifiers?  Or randomized unique values?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the size of your strings (and therefor IDs)? If you need constant unique numeric IDs across **all** possible strings your ID might not be limited in size.
So depending on your restrictions to this problem there might be no practical solution at all.

Comment: Yes, `ord` only works on a single byte. You could `ord` each character and do a digit sum or so to get a relatively small number. It won't be guaranteed to be unique though.

Comment: I update my code. I don't understand why -3 points... I need to create an ID to generate a JSON because database haven't unique ID, only has a string key.

Comment: Then why don't you use the string *as* id? An id doesn't have to be numeric. Or does it? Why?

Comment: Because I would like to use only numbers for the ID, and I thought there would be some easy way to do it

Comment: Then, no, there isn't, unless you can really clarify your situation and use case and that use case has enough restrictions to make something workable.

Comment: You could put the values into an array and use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove the duplicates - then use the indexes from that.

Comment: @kurtko: What is this ID going to be used for?  From one request to the next, does it need to remain consistent?  If not, then what is its purpose at all?  If so, then it sounds like your backing data needs an ID added to it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a limit for storing a value in int, but the String is not a limited length. Theoretically, sometimes there is always a collision.

So you would have to compress your arbitrary-length string to a non-arbitrary-length integer. This is impossible without data loss.

It is possible to use a hashing algorithm, but they can also match. Can not use automatic increment?

Comment: I need to create an ID to generate a JSON because database haven't unique ID, only has a string key.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really care what the IDs are, you can use the indexes from a unique array:

```
$a = "yellow";
$b = "green";
$c = "blue";
$d = "black";
$e = "blue";

$values = array($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);
$indexes = array_unique($values);

// print the index for the value
echo array_search($c, $indexes); // echos out "2"
```

The indexes array will look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => yellow
    [1] => green
    [2] => blue
    [3] => black
)
```